# Google Apps Script using wrong date format in excel

Tags: email, line, subject

So I am working on a Google Apps script that pulls an email address, subject, and body from a Google sheet file. This info is used to send an email out. Right now in my Subject column for the Google Sheets file I have =TODAY() so that the date is pulled.  My script updates this column everyday so the date is always current.

**The issue** is that when the email comes the subject line shows 
"Sat Aug 11 2018 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT) "

Instead of...

08/11/18 like its setup for in Google Sheets

Not sure why this could be, My code is below.

```js
/**
 * Creates a two time-driven triggers.
 */
function createTimeDrivenTriggers() {
  // Trigger every 6 hours.
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('adddate')
  .timeBased()
  .atHour(21)
  .everyDays(1)
  .inTimezone("America/Los_Angeles")
  .create()

  ScriptApp.newTrigger('sendEmails2')
  .timeBased()
  .atHour(22)
  .everyDays(1)
  .inTimezone("America/Los_Angeles")
  .create()
}
/**
 * This is my hacky way to make sure sheets has today's date.
 */
function adddate() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
var cell = sheet.getRange(2,2);
cell.setValue('=TODAY()');
    }

// This constant is written in column C for rows for which an email
// has been sent successfully.
var EMAIL_SENT = 'SUCCESSFULLY SENT';

/**
 * Sends non-duplicate emails with data from the current spreadsheet.
 */
function sendEmails2() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2; // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 2; // Number of rows to process
  // Fetch the range of cells A2:B3
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 3);
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[0]; // First column
    var subject = row[1]; // Second column
    var message = row[2]; // Third column
    var emailSent = row[3]; // Fourth column
    if (emailSent != EMAIL_SENT) { // Prevents sending duplicates
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
      sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 3).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
      // Make sure the cell is updated right away in case the script is interrupted
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are encountering is that your cell is formatted as a date and you are passing it as a parameter that expects a string. At that point you are no longer controlling the conversion, and you are getting way more than you wanted. Two ways to address it.
1) Make it a string in the first place with

```
cell.setValue('=text(TODAY(),"mm/dd/yy"');
```

which does run the risk of ruining any date processing you do on it at first (though I see none, so probably fine).

So probably better is (not 1, just this)
2) is to get the displayed string while leaving the underlying date like you had it with `var subject = row[1].getDisplayValue();`
2) has the added benefit of going with the date format for which sheets is set up.